# dynamically defining name for param in xsl

Tags: xslt

how can I provide the param name dynamically?

for ex: I have few parameters coming into xsl as input and each param hold xml content. however, in xsl I do not know how many params are going to come in runtime.

I have tried with following xsl but didn't work.

```
 <xsl:element name="param0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="concat('$','param0')/>
        </xsl:element>
```

but the following will gets the xml from param.

```
 <xsl:element name="param1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$param1"/>
        </xsl:element>
```

in runtime I know how many params are there but cannot define the same in xsl as the no.of params always changes for input.

Could you please let me know if this is even possible in xsl?

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what should be: _"in xsl I do not know how many params are going to come in runtime."_  In XSLT you have always to declare which parameters you are expecting with `xsl:param`.  This parameter can have default values (with slect="...").

Comment: Sometimes, I might have 2 params and sometimes 5 params and there is no limit on how many params are there for input. if I must need to declare the params, can I do it in side loop or template with dynamic name for it?

Comment: Kiran, <xsl:copy-of select="concat('$','param0')/> is missing the " at the end - maybe that's why it did not work? Best regarsd, Peter

Comment: Thanks Peter, but that's not the issue.

Comment: <xsl:element name="param0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="concat('$','$param0')"/>
        </xsl:element> from the concat name function, I want to return the value of "$newparam". the new param is the value got from $param0. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using concat() you get string value which is not evaluated as a variable. So although you think you pass a variable into xsl:copy you don't. You only copy a string.

I think you cannot do what you want with dynamic number of parameters in xslt. If you had params in form of separate files you could use collection() function from xslt 2.0. It could work for example in this way: `<xsl:variable name="params" select="collection('file:///path/to/params/param*.xml')"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have few parameters coming into xsl as input and each param hold xml content. however, in xsl I do not know how many params are going to come in runtime.

It sounds to me like you need to change the representation so that instead of passing several different parameters each holding one node, you instead pass *one* parameter with a fixed name whose value is a *node set*.  Exactly how this is accomplished depends on what processor you're using and how you're calling the stylesheet, but if it can be achieved then you can do things like

```
<xsl:for-each select="$params">
  <xsl:element name="param{position() - 1}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```